# SAMD21 - Hard fault on pointer dereference, debugger shows valid object

Tags: pointers, microcontroller, atmel

I'm hitting a hard fault in my program on my SAMD21 board, the fault occurs as soon as I access the pointer's value

```
iAP2Packet_t* iAP2LinkPacketForIndex (uint8_t* listArrayBuffer, uint8_t index)
{
    iAP2Packet_t** pPck = (iAP2Packet_t**) iAP2ListArrayItemForIndex(listArrayBuffer, index);
    if (pPck)
    {
        iAP2Packet_t* pPckU = *pPck;
        return pPckU;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

In the debugger I can see that pPck is pointing to valid data so I'm at a bit of a loss for how to debug this further.  Is there anyway to see what specific memory issue is causing the hard fault (pointer out of bounds, NULL ptr, etc.)?

[image]

Comment: It is not clear to me when the hard fault occurs: Does it if you run your program in non-debug mode? And if so, how do you know that it's the line you marked? Or does it happen if you execute one more line in the situation shown?

Comment: fairly unsafe way to use pointers/structs.  did you check the alignment in the disassembly?  and/or disable the alignment trap in the processor?

Comment: As suspected, the debugger screenshot confirms an unaligned value, highlighted in red. `pPck` points to a 2-byte aligned value but pointers must be 4-byte aligned on that 32 bit machine (it's an [ARM Cortex M0+](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0497a/BABFAIGG.html)). Workaround: copy the bytes out of your buffer into a variable with e.g. `memcpy`.

Comment: Thank you @YannVernier, adding 2 bytes of reserved alignment space fixed the issue.  Do you want to post your comment as an answer?